# Android force setProp on read-only properties on emulator

Tags: android, adb

Running `adb shell` to an emulator, trying to use setProp for readonly properties, eg `setprop ro.carrier newCarrier`, but it won't change it.

Is there a way to force overriding ro props?

Answer (score 5):

add `ro.carrier=newCarrier` to the `/system/build.prop` and reboot the instance

Comment: I'm running from within genymotion- is there a way to do so without reboot?